# Set navigation title for all view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'd like to set the title in the navigation bar in all my view controllers to the same value. Is it possible to do so in app delegate for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a common header, say `Common.h` in which; you can define macro like

`#define kGlobalTitle @"YourTitle"`

and then, import `Common.h` to `YourProjectName-Prefix.pch` file.

Now, you can use `self.title = kGlobalTitle;` in any ViewController, anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably subclass my UIViewController, customize it as I saw fit, and then base all of my other UIView subclasses of of this new base class.